# Multiple Choice Qns Test App using Flutter RadioListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

In my test app, I have questions that comes with 3 or 4 options to choose from. So I put the options into choices (in a class) as shown below, but how do I call for RadioListTile? since choices is in a 2d array.

```
class Test{
 var choices = [
    ["ABC", "AAB", "ACD"],           // 1st qns has 3 choices
    ["AND", "CQA", "QWE", "QAL"],    // 2nd qns has 4 choices
    ["ASD", "JUS", "JSB"]            // 3rd qns has 3 choices
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, Hope this might help

```
String _selection = '';

  List<List<String>> choices = [
    ["ABC", "AAB", "ACD"], // 1st qns has 3 choices
    ["AND", "CQA", "QWE", "QAL"], // 2nd qns has 4 choices
    ["ASD", "JUS", "JSB"] // 3rd qns has 3 choices
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Question here?'),
          Column(
            children: choices[0].map((item) { //change index of choices array as you need
              return RadioListTile(
                groupValue: _selection,
                title: Text(item),
                value: item,
                activeColor: Colors.blue,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  print(val);
                  setState(() {
                    _selection = val;
                  });
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```